# why my function dosnt work? (short one)

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to create a function that returning all the possibilities ways for a one place to another.

This is not my final code and I'm not sure if its working, but the error I get stopping me from continue.

The following is my python 2.7 code:

```
def routes(graph,start,end):
    path=[]
    paths=[]

    for node in graph[start]:
        if node==end:
            path+=[end]
        elif node<end:
            path.append(node)
            start=node
            routes(graph,start,end)
    return paths       

graph={001:(002),002:(003,004,005),003:(004),004:(005,006)}
routes(graph,002,005)
```

The problem starting when it enter the second function call.
when it tries to to run 'for node in graph[start]' line I'm getting an 'int' object is not iterable' error.

What can cause that error?

Why outside the recursion it works and inside it does not?

Thanks alot.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the return of your recursive call?

Comment: one problem is that `(002)` is an `int` and not a `tuple`. if you want this to be a `tuple` you need to write `(002, )` (note the comma).

Comment: tried that and its still does not work =/

Answer (score 1):

stolen from [here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) (may be a good read) and slightly updated:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

then this should give the desired result:

```
graph = {1: (2, ), 2: (3, 4, 5), 3: (4, ), 4: (5, 6)}
print(find_all_paths(graph=graph, start=2, end=5))
# -> [[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]]
```

maybe compare that to your version and find out where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> still does not work

Basically you just missed to assign the found paths to `paths` and to insert the start node before `return`ing. A corrected version:

```
def routes(graph,start,end):
    paths=[]
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node==end:
            paths+=[[end]]
        elif node<end:
            paths+=routes(graph,node,end)
    for path in paths:
        path.insert(0, start)
    return paths

graph={001:(002,),002:(003,004,005),003:(004,),004:(005,006)}
print routes(graph,002,005)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5]]
```